# How to use plsql-parser (ANTLR)

Tags: plsql, antlr

I'd like to check PL/SQL query syntax in automated tests, and it looks like https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser might be useful for that. I am not easily finding out how I would install and use it though.

Note that this is for a Ruby project, but I'm reasonably competent in Java. I'm hoping there's some way I can run the checking via console, pass in the SQL, and get back any error info, including line/column.

Thanks.

Comment: Why kind of statements do you want to check? And can you connect to an Oracle server? Because `DBMS_SQL.PARSE` can verify a statement as well.

Comment: In this case, neither the Oracle server/database that is accessed in production not any other Oracle database server is available to us outside of the actual production environment. I am hoping we can change that situation soonish, but it would at least be helpful to know up front that the SQL is syntactically correct. We are checking that manually now by printing the generated SQL and pasting it into one of the SQL formatting Web sites that supports Oracle.

Comment: I assume you are dynamically generating SQL or anonymous pl/sql blocks from ruby, then running them in Oracle? (sometimes failing due to syntax?).  If so, why not create a package/procedure/function in Oracle that will take your SQL and parse it for you (using dbms_sql.parse as suggested by ahorsewithnoname), returning any errors.

Comment: @tbone, the problem is the "running them in Oracle" part. Currently, we don't have access to any Oracle server in which to parse them. Of course, I do intend to try to get that in the future, so perhaps that's the best answer. I was hoping the ANLTR parser would be an easy solution in the mean time though. Perhaps, it's not so easy?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm afraid that DBMS_SQL.PARGE supports only pure SQL - but not PL/SQL. Also that mentined parser is a little bit relaxed. I some cases it accepts an input which is syntactically incorrect. And also it can not spot any semantic errors.

Comment: @Steve Jorgensen - what exactly to you need. SQL only? You you need to only validate the input? Or do you need to understand the query structure - the AST (abstract syntax tree) ?

Comment: @Ivan : I only need to validate queries (not procedures) but need to validate with respect to Oracle's query syntax. I do not need the AST, just location and nature of errors. Presumably, a tool that can to that well would also build an AST? but I don't need access to the AST.

Answer (score 4):

- Download the ANTLR tool ver 3.5.1
- Download the source codes from [here](https://github.com/ibre5041/plsql-parser/commits/master) (as this version was ported to 3.5.1)
- Use the tool to compile the sources from poarsers/no-ast subdir
- 1st compile PLSQLLexer.g
- 2nd compile PLSQLParser.g from no-ast subdir
- the use this sample code as an example:

```
    import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRNoCaseFileStream;
    import org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
    import org.antlr.runtime.RecognitionException;

    import br.com.porcelli.parser.plsql.PLSQLLexer;
    import br.com.porcelli.parser.plsql.PLSQLParser;

public static void parse(String file) {
    try {
        PLSQLLexer lex = new PLSQLLexer(new ANTLRNoCaseFileStream(file));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        PLSQLParser parser = new PLSQLParser(tokens);

        /*start_rule_return AST =*/ parser.data_manipulation_language_statements();

        System.err.println(file +": " + parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors());

        if(parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() != 0)
        {
            //System.exit(1);
        }

    } catch (RecognitionException e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    } catch (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError e) {
        System.err.println(file + ":");
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.err.println(file + ":");
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }       
}
```

Comment: Did you succeded in, @SteveJorgensen?

Comment: I'm afraid I can no longer remember if I succeeded or not. At least I have this for reference if I have need to try it again.

Comment: How much time it takes to build? I'm doing this and feeling it is taking so much time and console shows nothing.