# How to use porcelli plsql-parser (ANTLR)

Tags: java, parsing, plsql, antlr, antlr3

I am new in ANTLR. My requirement is to programaticaly parse a PL/SQL block and to be able to format it based on some conditions.For example:

1) I want to find all the commented code inside the SQL block.

2) I should be able to write back the parsed/edited object back in some sql file.

Currently I have compiled the plsql-parser available at [porcelli/pl-sql](https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser).
I also went through this helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637991/how-to-use-plsql-parser-antlr). So in a nutshell I have parsed the sql block.

```
    PLSQLLexer lex = new PLSQLLexer(new ANTLRNoCaseFileStream(file));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
    PLSQLParser parser = new PLSQLParser(tokens);

    /*start_rule_return AST =*/ parser.data_manipulation_language_statements();

    System.err.println(file +": " + parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors());
 //This is the place I want to build my tree 
 // parser.setBuildParseTree(true);
  //ParseTree tree = parser.plsql_block();
```

I need some help, useful links in this direction. I am new in ANTLR; so any help in any direction will be appreciated.