# how to use PLSQL parser in target language as java

Tags: java, parsing, plsql

I am newbie in pl sql parsing. I am using [porcelli](https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser), and gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637991/how-to-use-plsql-parser-antlr).

But I am not able to configure this in my eclipse or my local system.

Are there any tutorial or detailed steps for using procelli.

Also I'll be parsing package file. Is porcelli is correct to use?
Once after setting up all, I need to extract all the function and respective params in the package file. How to proceed for that?